get network error when use axios post file
I'm use axios to post data to laravel,but I got different result when use different way to get file.
I want to know why I get the error.
when I use e.target.files, I can post the file to laravel.
here is the program in uploader.jsx
uploadApi('upload',{"multiple":props.multiple,"image":e.target.files[0]})
.then((res) => {
  if(res.data.msg){
    alert("upload fail!");
  }
});

but when I use ref to get file, I got Network error from axios.
here is the program in homepage.jsx
const update = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve)=>{
    uploadApi('homeVisionUpload',{"id":carouselID,"image":fileRef.current.files[0]})
    .then((res) => {
      if(res.data.msg){
        alert("update fail!");
      }
      else{
        init();
        resolve(true);
      }
    });
  })
}

here is the input setting
<input className="form-control" ref={props.fileRef} type="file" id={props.id} onChange={e=>handleChange(e)} multiple={props.multiple}/>

the flow is upload file->handleChange() in uploader.jsx->click update botton->update() in homepage.jsx
here is uploadApi function
const uploadApi = (urlCode,data) => {
 const loader = document.querySelector('.loader-container');
 if(loader){
   loader.style.display = "flex";
 }
 return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
  setting(urlCode, data).then((res) => {

    const formData = new FormData();
    Object.keys(res.body.body).forEach((key)=>{
      formData.append(key,res.body.body[key]);
    })
    for (var key of formData.entries()) {
      console.log(key[0] + ', ' + key[1]);
    }
    request.post(res.header.url,formData,{
      headers:
        {
          'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data'
        }
      }).then((res) => {
      // alert("upload success");
      resolve(res)
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log('error api');
      reject(err);
    })
    .finally(()=>{
      if(loader){
        loader.style.display = "none";
      }
    });
  })
 })
}

I change handleChange function and use fileRef there, and it can sent the file correctly.
what the different with the update function?
const handleChange = (e) => {
uploadApi('upload',{"multiple":props.multiple,"image":props.fileRef.current.files[0]})
.then((res) => {
  if(res.data.msg){
    alert("upload fail!");
  }

});

and I check the api url is correct,the point is only on the file.
